# How to find the optimal path for a graph with weighted edges using depth first search method?

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to solve ["Problem Set 2: Fastest Way to Get Around MIT"](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0002-introduction-to-computational-thinking-and-data-science-fall-2016/assignments/) from [MIT Course Number 6.0002](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0002-introduction-to-computational-thinking-and-data-science-fall-2016/):

> In this problem set you will solve a simple optimization problem on a graph. Specifically, you will find the shortest route from one building to another on the MIT campus given that you wish to constrain the amount of time you spend walking outdoors (in the cold). [...]
>
> ### Problem 3: Find the Shortest Path using Optimized Depth First Search
>
> In our campus map problem, the total distance traveled on a path is equal to the sum of all total distances traveled between adjacent nodes on this path. Similarly, the distance spent outdoors on the path is equal to the sum of all distances spent outdoors on the edges in the path.
>
> Depending on the number of nodes and edges in a graph, there can be multiple valid paths from one node to another, which may consist of varying distances. We define the shortest path between two nodes to be the path with the least total distance traveled . You are trying to minimize the distance traveled while not exceeding the maximum distance outdoors.
>
> How do we find a path in the graph? Work off the depth-first traversal algorithm covered in lecture to discover each of the nodes and their children nodes to build up possible paths. Note that you’ll have to adapt the algorithm to fit this problem. [...]
>
> #### Problem 3b: Implement get_best_path
>
> Implement the helper function `get_best_path`. Assume that any variables you need have been set correctly in `directed_dfs`. Below is some pseudocode to help get you started.
>
> ```
> if start and end are not valid nodes: 
>     raise an error 
> elif start and end are the same node: 
>     update the global variables appropriately
> else:
>     for all the child nodes of start
>         construct a path including that node
>         recursively solve the rest of the path, from the child node to the end node
>
> return the shortest path
> ```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong in the algorithm to find the shortest path using the depth-first search method.

I tried unweighted edges and it works fine for that, but when I try weighted edges it does not return the shortest path.

```
def get_best_path(digraph, start, end, path, max_dist_outdoors, best_dist,
                  best_path):
    """
    Finds the shortest path between buildings subject to constraints.

    Parameters:
        digraph: Digraph instance
            The graph on which to carry out the search
        start: string
            Building number at which to start
        end: string
            Building number at which to end
        path: list composed of [[list of strings], int, int]
            Represents the current path of nodes being traversed. Contains
            a list of node names, total distance traveled, and total
            distance outdoors.
        max_dist_outdoors: int
            Maximum distance spent outdoors on a path
        best_dist: int
            The smallest distance between the original start and end node
            for the initial problem that you are trying to solve
        best_path: list of strings
            The shortest path found so far between the original start
            and end node.

    Returns:

        a list of building numbers (in strings), [n_1, n_2, ..., n_k],
        where there exists an edge from n_i to n_(i+1) in digraph,
        for all 1 <= i < k and the distance of that path.

        If there exists no path that satisfies max_total_dist and
        max_dist_outdoors constraints, then return None.
    """
    # TODO
    # put the first node in the path on each recursion
    path[0] = path[0] +  [start]
    # if start and end nodes are same then return the path
    if start == end:
        return tuple(path[0])

    # create a node from the start point name
    start_node = Node(start)

    # for each edge starting at that start node, call the function recursively
    # if the destination node is not already in path
    # and if the best_dist has not been found yet or it is greater than the total distance 
    # current path
    for an_edge in digraph.get_edges_for_node(start_node):
        # get the destination node for the edge
        a_node = an_edge.get_destination()
        # update the total distance traveled so far
        path[1] = path[1] + an_edge.get_total_distance()
        # update the distance spent outside
        path[2] = path[2] + an_edge.get_outdoor_distance()

        # if the node is not in path
        if str(a_node) not in path[0]:
            # if the best_distance is none or greater than distance of current path
            if  path[1] < best_dist and path[2] < max_dist_outdoors:
                new_path = get_best_path(digraph, str(a_node), end, [path[0], path[1], path[2]], max_dist_outdoors, best_dist, best_path)
                if new_path != None:
                    best_dist = path[1]
                    print('best_dist', best_dist)
                    best_path = new_path
    return best_path
```

Comment: How do you call this method? Can you give a concrete example? It looks weird that you have to pass so many arguments. Normally for such a function you would only need to pass the first three.

Comment: Why did you not reply to my inquiry?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. the method is called by the test cases that are provided in the ps2.py in the mit problem set when you download and unzip that

Comment: Your question should contain all necessary information *in line*, not behind a link.

Comment: Well i can't post the rest of the stuff right now but i will do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_best_path(digraph, start, end, path, max_dist_outdoors, best_dist, best_path):
    start_node = Node(start)                                                                                                                                                                                     
    end_node = Node(end)                                                                                                                                                                                         
    path[0] = path[0] + [start]                                                                                                                                                                                  
    if len(path[0]) > 1:                                                                                                                                                                                         
        dist, out_dist = get_distances_for_node(digraph, Node(path[0][-2]), start_node)                                                                                                                          
        path[1] = path[1] + dist                                                                                                                                                                                 
        path[2] = path[2] + out_dist                                                                                                                                                                             
    if not digraph.has_node(start_node) and not digraph.has_node(end_node):                                                                                                                                      
        raise ValueError('The graph does not contain these nodes')                                                                                                                                               
    elif start_node == end_node:                                                                                                                                                                                 
        return (path[0], path[1])                                                                                                                                                                                
    else:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        for an_edge in digraph.get_edges_for_node(start_node):                                                                                                                                                   
            next_node = an_edge.get_destination()                                                                                                                                                                
            if str(next_node) not in path[0]:                                                                                                                                                                    
                expected_dist = path[1] + an_edge.get_total_distance()                                                                                                                                           
                expected_out_dist = path[2] + an_edge.get_outdoor_distance()                                                                                                                                     
                if expected_dist < best_dist and expected_out_dist <= max_dist_outdoors:                                                                                                                         
                    #print('best_path_check', path[1], best_dist)                                                                                                                                                
                    new_path = get_best_path(digraph, str(next_node), end, [path[0], path[1], path[2]], max_dist_outdoors, best_dist, best_path)                                                                 
                    #print(new_path)                                                                                                                                                                             
                    if new_path[0] != None:                                                                                                                                                                      
                        best_path = new_path[0]                                                                                                                                                                  
                        best_dist = new_path[1]                                                                                                                                                                  
    return (best_path, best_dist)    

def get_distances_for_node(digraph, src, dest):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    for an_edge in digraph.get_edges_for_node(src):                                                                                                                                                              
        if an_edge.get_destination() == dest:                                                                                                                                                                    
            return an_edge.get_total_distance(), an_edge.get_outdoor_distance()
```

I was able to solve my problem using this function but i am not sure whether it is the best solution.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I see you used several of the points I raised in my answer, including the use of the combined return value (with best_dist). I wonder how that could work though, since the exercise (and your question) specifies that the return value of `get_best_path` must be a list of buildings, not a tuple of path and distance.

Comment: the docstring value of method says
Returns:
          A tuple with the shortest-path from start to end, represented by
          a list of building numbers (in strings), [n_1, n_2, ..., n_k],
          where there exists an edge from n_i to n_(i+1) in digraph,
          for all 1 <= i < k and **the distance of that path.** 
          If there exists no path that satisfies max_total_dist and
          max_dist_outdoors constraints, then return None.

I also missed on the ** and the distance of that path** and just returned tuple initially but then i reread it and tried again.

Comment: I am sorry for not responding early because i was at work and so i did not check my stackoverflow question.

Comment: Oh so the docstring you specified in the question is missing *"A tuple with the shortest-path from start to end, represented by"*.  That was a crucial phrase to omit. Pfff... wasted my time on this question :/